# Java6 ключевое слово final в теле метода по отношению к ссылке на объект

Tags: android, java

Нарвался в инете на такое применение ключевого слова final, но никак не могу понять его практический смысл?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Практический смысл в данном контексте лишь один - исключить возможность присваивания переменной нового значения. Многие следуют принципу: всегда использовать `final`, если ситуация не требует опускания этого модификатора..

Comment: Хм, то есть типа самостраховка что-ли, как многие применяют фигурные скобки после if, даже если там одна инструкция?? А у Вас не найдется ссылочка на статью, где это написано или в какой книге вы это вычитали?

Comment: @MDJHD Ссылочка не найдется. Скорее это вопрос привычки. Мне нравится везде использовать final, но к примеру на работе у нас так не принято.

Comment: Спасибо. Полистал пару форумов, никакого "глубинного" смысла в этом стиле не нашел. Пишем дальше как писали раньше :)

Comment: @MDJHD: Точно такой же смысл, как и в объявлении полей private. Страховка от себя, от коллег, от опечаток, от непреднамеренных ошибок.

Comment: Ну я бы не сравнивал муху со слоном :) на private (инкапсуляции) можно сказать весь ООП держится!

Comment: @MDJHD: Смотрите глубже: а **для чего** нужна инкапсуляция? Для чего скрывать детали реализации?

Comment: ИМХО если так глубоко копать, то и языки программирования можно признать всего-лишь удобным способом писать машинные команды. Но без них современный мир скорее всего не бы был таким, а вот без этого final можно смело обходиться. Так что муха vs слон :)))

Comment: а попробуйте использовать не final переменную, объявленную в методе, в колбэке... IDE будет ругаться

Comment: @Gorets Это иной контекст, нежели в вопросе. Еще можно вспомнить про `final` у полей класса. Там дополнительная семантика появляется. Но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: @MDJHD: Не, вы копаете не в ту сторону. Инкапсуляция и нужна для того, чтобы _предотвратить неверное случайное использование_ внутренней информации класса, в частности, незапланированного доступа к его переменным. И именно для этого же и служит `final`: он дополнительно подчёркивает ожидаемую, запланированную логику использования переменной.

Comment: @Gorets потому что без final она будет на стеке. А final переносит её в кучу для использования в колбеке. Сохранение контекста короче.